# Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Чёт не могу понять, на входе объект есть, а не фетчится
вот код

```
static function db_get_users($ids){
        $status = self::db_status();
        if ($status == false):
            throw new \Exception('Немає з’єднання з базою данних!');
        else:
            $bd = self::db_connect();
           $arRezult = array();
            foreach ($ids as $id):
                $bd->real_query("SELECT `fio` FROM `users` WHERE `id` LIKE ".$id);
                $ret = $bd->use_result();
                while ($row = $ret->fetch_row()):
                    array_push($arRezult, $row[0]);
                endwhile;
            endforeach;
            return $arRezult;
        endif;
    }
```

Он дергается периодически аяксом и выводит список юзеров по переданному ранее списку id и собственно возвращает список фио.
массив с id существует, см. скрин, там я его вывел, юзеры в бд присутствуют, ушел на обед - работает, пришел - не работает Возвращает ошибку фетчинга в `while`

[image: вывод объекта и массива]

и скрин юзеров с бд
[image: юзеры]

и скрин с кодом там где ошибку пишет
[image: код]

Comment: Запросы в цикле, нехешированные пароли, понятно

Comment: Ну если Вы подскажете более удобный способ перебирать массив с ид-шками юзеров для получения их фио - буду благодарен, а нсчет хеширования - я отлично знаю что оно должно быть, но таково пожелание заказчика, так что.. давайте лучше по делу комментить.

Comment: `WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, проблема была в массиве с юзерами, разделителем был пробел, и при наличии лишнего пробела - цикл коротился, так как id c = ""; не существует.